# Submit form with Get method in MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following form:

```
@model Teesa.Models.SearchModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "SearchForm" }))
{
    <div class="top-menu-search-buttons-div">
        @if (!MvcHtmlString.IsNullOrEmpty(Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SearchText)))
        {
            <style type="text/css">
                .top-menu-search-text
                {
                    border: solid 1px red;
                }
            </style>
        }
        @Html.TextBoxFor(q => q.SearchText, new { @class = "top-menu-search-text", id = "SearchText", name = "SearchText" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(q=>q.Page)
        <input type="submit" value="search" class="top-menu-search-submit-button" />
    </div>
    <div id="top-menu-search-info" class="top-menu-search-info-div">
        Please Select one :
        <hr style="background-color: #ccc; height: 1px;" />
        <div class="top-menu-search-info-checkbox-div">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(q => q.SearchInBooks, new { id = "SearchInBooks", name = "SearchInBooks" })
            <label for="SearchInBooks">Books</label>
        </div>
        <div class="top-menu-search-info-checkbox-div">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(q => q.SearchInAuthors, new { id = "SearchInAuthors" })
            <label for="SearchInAuthors">Authors</label>
        </div>
        <div class="top-menu-search-info-checkbox-div">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(q => q.SearchInTags, new { id = "SearchInTags" })
            <label for="SearchInTags">Tags</label>
        </div>
}
```

and the following Controller and Models :

```
namespace Teesa.Models
{
    public class SearchModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
        public string SearchText { get; set; }
        public bool SearchInTags { get; set; }
        public bool SearchInAuthors { get; set; }
        public bool SearchInBooks { get; set; }
        public int Page { get; set; }
        public List<SearchBookModel> Result { get; set; }
        public List<SimilarBookModel> LatestBooks { get; set; }
    }

    public class SearchBookModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Summary { get; set; }
        public List<Tags> Tags { get; set; }
        public string StatusName { get; set; }
        public string SubjectName { get; set; }
        public string ThumbnailImagePath { get; set; }
        public string BookRate { get; set; }
        public string RegistrationDate { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfVisit { get; set; }
    }
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(SearchModel model)
{
    FillSearchModel(model);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
            string page = model.Page;
        DatabaseInteract databaseInteract = new DatabaseInteract();
        model.Result = new List<SearchBookModel>();
        List<Book> allBooks = databaseInteract.GetAllBooks();
        List<Book> result = new List<Book>();
        #region 
        if (model.SearchInTags)
        {
            var temp = (from item in allBooks
                        from tagItem in item.Tags
                        where tagItem.Name.Contains(model.SearchText)
                        select item).ToList();
            result.AddRange(temp);
        }
        if (model.SearchInBooks)
        {
            var temp = (from item in allBooks
                        where item.عنوان.Contains(model.SearchText)
                        select item).ToList();
            result.AddRange(temp);
        }
        if (model.SearchInAuthors)
        {
            var temp = (from item in allBooks
                        where item.Author.Contains(model.SearchText)
                        select item).ToList();
            result.AddRange(temp);
        }
        #endregion
        #region Paging
        string itemsPerPage = databaseInteract.GetItemsPerPage();
        int ItemInPage = int.Parse(itemsPerPage);
        var pagingParams = Helpers.SetPagerParameters(page, ItemInPage, result);
        ViewBag.AllPagesCount = pagingParams.AllPagesCount;
        ViewBag.CurrentPageNumber = pagingParams.CurrentPageNumber;
        ViewBag.CountOfAllItems = pagingParams.CountOfAllItems.ToMoneyFormat().ToPersianNumber();
        result = pagingParams.ListData as List<Book> ?? result;
        #endregion
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            var bookRate = (item.BookRate == null || item.BookRate.Count == 0)
                               ? 0.0
                               : item.BookRate.Average(q => q.Rate);
            model.Result.Add(new SearchBookModel
            {
                Author = item.Author,
                Id = item.Id,
                .
                .
                .
            });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        model.Result = new List<SearchBookModel>();
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

When I submit the form I see the following query strings(Notice the duplicate names) :

```
http://localhost:2817/Search?SearchText=book&Page=2&SearchInBooks=true&SearchInBooks=false&SearchInAuthors=true&SearchInAuthors=false&SearchInTags=true&SearchInTags=false
```

But it has to be something like this :

```
http://localhost:2817/Search?SearchText=book&Page=2&SearchInBooks=true&SearchInAuthors=true&SearchInTags=true
```

How can I fix it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Html.Checkbox` (and the related `For...` methods) generate a hidden input for false, and the checkbox for true. This is to ensure that model binding works consistently when binding.

If you must get rid of "false" items resulting from the hidden inputs,  you'll need to construct the checkbox inputs yourself (using HTML and not the helper).

```
<input type="checkbox" id="SearchInBooks" name="SearchInBooks">
```

Comment: So, How can I bind it to the Model ? !

Comment: When you do a post method it will bind your results back to the model. See my answer!

Comment: @Mohammad you will not have to change anything in terms of model binding. That part should still work as it stands in your example (model binding also works against query string arguments).

Comment: I guess when you use the normal checkbox you'll get into trouble in model binding when you submit the form from firefox. Firefox sends the value as "on" when the checkbox is checked and you'll get a binding error

Comment: @Mohammad you could override binding for `SearchModel`, or you could intercept the form submit using jQuery, and construct the redirect URL so it uses 'true'/'false' safely.

Comment: @Mohammad you can submit the form using jquery by listening to the submit event

Answer (score 1):

Why dont your create a Post Method with a matching name to the Get method. This will ensure that the code is much easier to debug. As you will not have a huge function to go through trying to find problems like this.

I cannot find a where your getting the duplicate url query strings from though.

This will also allow you to bind your results back to the model.

Comment: The whole point of using a GET in this instance is to ensure that users can bookmark the results pages, with the query intact, which wouldn't be possible using a POST.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid Ah i see. I didnt know this, i am pretty new to MVC myself. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the model binding to happen successfully then you have to go with this way because that is the nature of the `Html.CheckBox/Html.CheckBoxFor` methods they will render a hidden field as well.

I would suggest rather go with POST to make your life easy. If you still want to use GET then you have to use checkbox elements directly but you have to take care of the model binding issues. Not all the browsers returns "true" when the checkbox is checked for ex. firefox passes "on" so the default model binder throws an error.

Other alternate options is you can go for custom model binder or you can submit the form using jquery by listening to the submit event.